# InlineKeyboardMakeup is shown, but doesnt resrond

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I am new to telegram bots. I read about Inline keyboards and try to create my own one. here is my code:

```
def Choice(bot,update):
    quest = [[InlineKeyboardButton('1st question', callback_data = '1'),
              InlineKeyboardButton('2nd question', callback_data = '2')]]
    reply = InlineKeyboardMarkup(quest)                                      
    update.message.reply_text('Test', reply_markup = reply)
test = CommandHandler('test', Choice)
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(test)
```

The problem is that it shows keyboard, but there is no answer. Please, help me )

I tried:

```
def Choice(bot,update):
    quest = [[InlineKeyboardButton('1st question', callback_data = '1'),
              InlineKeyboardButton('2nd question', callback_data = '2')]]
    reply = InlineKeyboardMarkup(quest)                                      
    update.message.reply_text('Test', reply_markup = reply)

def button(bot, update):
query = update.callback_query

bot.edit_message_text(text="Selected option: {}".format(query.data),
                      chat_id=query.message.chat_id,
                      message_id=query.message.message_id)
test = CommandHandler('test', Choice)
buttonB = CallbackQueryHandler(button)
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(test)
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(buttonB)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [CallbackQueryHandler](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.callbackqueryhandler.html).

> Handler class to handle Telegram callback queries. Optionally based on a regex.

Comment: I guess, i do it wrong ((
Is there tutorial of some kind?
Thx